# Зазор между Status Bar и Toolbar

Tags: android, android-toolbar

Всем привет, не мог бы мне кто нибудь помочь? Дело в том, что я заменил Action Bar на Toolbar, и так вышло что появился белый зазор над Toolbar. В настройках телефона включил границы элементов, увидел, что там есть какой-то элемент. Что делать? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Main

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:background="#dddddd"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        />

        <TabHost
            android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TabWidget
                    android:id="@android:id/tabs"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:tabStripEnabled="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="43dp">

                </TabWidget>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                            xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                            android:id="@+id/card_view"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="60dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="top"
                            card_view:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="12dp">

                            <RelativeLayout
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:onClick="clicked">

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/info_text"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:text="Что такое HTML?"
                                    android:gravity="start"
                                    android:textSize="14sp"
                                    android:paddingTop="12dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"
                                    android:textColor="#000000"/>

                                <TextView
                                    android:id="@+id/info_text"
                                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:text="Разберёмся, что представляет из себя HTML."
                                    android:textSize="11sp"
                                    android:gravity="bottom|left"
                                    android:paddingBottom="12dp"
                                    android:paddingLeft="8dp"/>

                                <ImageButton
                                    android:id="@+id/html_lesson_1"
                                    android:background="@drawable/arrow_paddinged"
                                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                                    android:padding="15dp"/>

                            </RelativeLayout>

                        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:id="@+id/tab3"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    </LinearLayout>

                </FrameLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </TabHost>


    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: попробуйте для тулбара добавить минимальный  размер по вертикали `android:minHeight="?android:actionBarSize"`

Comment: Я уже понял, в чём проблема. Проблема в сторонней библиотеке, которую я использую для nav drawer. Но всё равно спасибо за уделённое время.

Comment: если вы самостоятельно нашли решение, оформите его, как ответ (кнопка "ответить на собственный вопрос"). это поможет другим участникам быстрее решить аналогичную проблему

Comment: @pavlofff спасибо за подсказку. Я здесь новичок и только учусь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решена! Дело в сторонней библиотеке com.mikepenz.materialdrawer, которую я использовал для создания Navigation Drawer. Библиотека имеет такую ошибку. Поэтому я удалил её из своего проекта.